# Text processing to concatenate lines (ie remove end of line char)

Tags: emacs

I have a list of lines like this:

```
a+
b+
c+
d+
e+
f+
... you get the idea...
```

I want to end up with a+b+c+d+e etc

I was trying with emacs but couldn't work out how to do such a thing.  anyone any ideas?

One thing that does work is 
    c-m-% [paste in selected after + on one line to beginning of next row]  [nothing]

There must be something to insert for carriage return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply replacing EOLs by nothing?

<kbd>M-%</kbd><kbd>C-q C-j</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

Explanation:

- <kbd>M-%</kbd> : query-replace
- <kbd>C-q</kbd> : quote the following character
- <kbd>C-j</kbd> : end-of-line character
- first <kbd>RET</kbd> : validate the search string
- second <kbd>RET</kbd> : validate the (empty) replacement string

Comment: Thats what I was really after, thanks.  So C-j is the end of line char?

Comment: Yes, `C-j` is EOL. This explains why it is by default bound to `newline-and-indent` in Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a buffer with those lines in it? In that case, you could create a simple macro:

```
F3  ;; record macro
C-e ;; end of line
C-d ;; delete newline
F4  ;; save macro
```

Then either press F4 repeatedly until you're done, or do `C-0 F4` to do it all in one swoop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just `M-q' ?  The spacing is different, and it will use several lines if you have many of those thingies, but otherwise, it seems like a funny alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
M-x
replace-regexp
RET
C-q C-j
RET
RET
```